# Помогите разобраться с popup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

У меня есть popup-окно, в закрытом состоянии отображается envelope, нажимая на него, появляется popup-окно, envelope должен исчезать, а вместо него должен появляться close. Но у меня envelope и close  меняются поочередно...не так, как должно быть...подскажите пожалуйста

script.js:

```
// отображается envelope для для запуска popup window
$('.show_popup').click(function() {
    var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel"));
    $(popup_id).show();
    $('.overlay_popup').show();
})
$('.overlay_popup').click(function() {
    $('.overlay_popup, .popup').hide();
})

//c закомментированным кодом ниже работает неправильно
// $('.envelope').click(function () {
//     $('.envelope').hide();
//     $('.close').show();
// })
// $('.close').click(function () {
//     $('.close').hide();
//     $('.envelope').show();
// })
```

index.php:

```
<div class="content">
<!-- icon element on the screen-->
<div class="show_popup blue-circle" rel="popup1">
    <i class="fa  fa-envelope-o envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay_popup"></div>

<!-- popup element -->
<div class="popup" id="popup1">    
    <div id="text"></div>    
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.popup,
.overlay_popup {
display: none;
}
.close {
display: none;
}
.overlay_popup {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 2;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.popup {
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
left: 87%;
top: 93%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
max-width: 200px;
padding: 20px;
background: #fff;
z-index: 1;
}

.blue-circle {
position: fixed;
left: 85%;
top: 90%;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #03a9f5;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2;
}
.blue-circle i {
color: #ecfeff;
font-size: 25px;
margin-top: 7px;
}
```

Comment: во первых строчкой 
var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel")); 
ты ищешь id элемента. id элемента это  строчка или число , но никак не jquery обьект

Comment: что именно ерунда?

Comment: @ruslik, извиняюсь, но, `var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel"));` - тут присваивается jquery объект переменной `popup_id`, но никак не "во первых строчкой ... ты ищешь id элемента". Id элемента тут не ищется, в этом вы не правы, но при этом вы правы, что это явно не то, что хочет использовать автор, ибо потом это опять оборачивает в  `$(popup_id)`

Comment: я имел ввиду что по логике он ищет id элемента, и логичнее было написать popup

Comment: мне нужно, чтоб при закрытом popup было envelope, а при открытом - close...много всяких вариантов перепробовал, в вопрос написал один из них просто

Comment: так и пиши что когда я открываю попап, то покажи мне эту кннопку

Comment: $('.overlay_popup').click(function() {
    $('.overlay_popup, .popup').hide();
    $('.envelope').show();
})

Comment: тоже не срабатывает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
const $envelope = $('.envelope'),
  $popup = $('.popup'),
  $popupOverlay = $('.overlay_popup'),
  $popupClose = $('.close');

$envelope.on('click', showPopup);
$popupClose.on('click', hidePopup);

function showPopup() {
  $envelope.hide();
  $popupClose.show();
  $popupOverlay.show();
  $popup.filter(`#${$(this).closest('.show_popup').attr('rel')}`).show();
}

function hidePopup() {
  $envelope.show();
  $popupClose.hide();
  $popupOverlay.hide();
  $popup.hide();
}
```

Comment: не срабатывает...

Comment: @Александр, больше бы информации, если рассуждать "в слепую", то все должно было сработать. Можете предоставить вариант (хотя бы без стилей), который бы работал хотя бы как-то)?

Comment: мой вариант работает, только неправильно, сейчас допишу в коде

Comment: @Александр, кажется нашел в чем проблема (не сразу сообразил какая разметка), попробуйте так (обновил ответ).

Comment: @Александр, не разбирался в вашем варианте, но у вас там как минимум та же самая ошибка которую перенес к себе я (вы ищете `rel` у иконки, а он указан у родителя)

Comment: Да и вообще, я бы смотрел клик именно по родителю, а не по иконке (более практично).

Comment: @Александр, и да, хватит плюсовать все комментарии ... Мы тут что бы развивать сообщество, а не что бы лайки накручивать, апать комментарии и ответы стоит только когда ответ реально имеет практическую пользу для сообщества xDD

Comment: Ваши ответы ВСЕ важны, т.к. помогают разобраться!  Ваш код не срабатывает, вернее при нажатии на конверт, открывается popup, конверт исчезает, появляется крест и на этом работоспособность popup заканчивается....т.е. popup не закрывается, а крестик так и остается

Comment: @Александр, это уже похоже на то, что крест просто перекрывается попапом. Попробуйте кликнуть по нему правой кнопкой и "посмотреть код", скорее всего у вас выберется попап, а не крест. Тут уже дело верстки, а не попапа. Специально сделал [имитацию на кодпене](https://codepen.io/MedvedevDev/pen/eGdxxa), там все верно работает. Думаю вам остается лишь решить проблему со стилями.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66038/discussion-between--and-medvedevdev).